# Extract subsets with specified number of elements from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In python 3, I have been trying to find a way to extract subsets from a list given a number that specifies how elements I want, and also in the correct order. 
For instance: for the list `L = [7, 6, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5]`, say I want subsets with 7 elements, there would only be two subsets which are `[7, 6, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2]` and `[6, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5]`.
Is there a way for me to perform this operation? Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score -2):

Will this work?

```
def subsets(chunks,list1):
    d=(len(L)+1-chunks)
    return [L[i:i + chunks] for i in range(0,d,1)]

print(subsets(7,L))
```

output:

```
[[7, 6, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2], [6, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5]]
```